# Bug with building SSR for reactjs-website

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack, server-side-rendering

I have some react-app and trying to enable server-side rendering.

1. I make the `server/index.js` and describe the server logic (using `express`)

```
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import express from 'express';

import App from 'src/App';

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3006;
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const app = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App />);
  const indexFile = path.resolve('./build/index.html'); <-- it's result of `npm run build`

  fs.readFile(indexFile, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Something went wrong:', err);
      return res.status(500).send('Oops, better luck next time!');
    }

    return res.send(
      data.replace('<div id="root"></div>', `<div id="root">${app}</div>`)
    );
  });
});

app.use(express.static('./build'));

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

2. Then I use webpack for convert jsx to js

```
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: './server/index.js',
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  devtool: false,
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('build'),
    filename: 'server.js',
    asyncChunks: true,
    clean: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: { presets: ['solid'] },
          },
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
              compilerOptions: { noEmit: false },
            }
          }],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          "css-loader", // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          "sass-loader", // Compiles Sass to CSS
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin()
  ],
  resolve: {
    roots: [
      'node_modules'
    ],
    alias: {
      src: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
    },
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
};
```

3. Then I try to start server `node build/server.js` but got some error

```
/* harmony import */ var solid_js_web__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! solid-js/web */ "./node_modules/solid-js/web/dist/server.js");

...

const _tmpl$ = /*#__PURE__*/(0,solid_js_web__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.template)(`<li></li>`, 2),
TypeError: (0 , solid_js_web__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.template) is not a function
```

I can't understand how it happened and what's wrong? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake in webpack config

```
{
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
        presets: ['@babel/env', '@babel/preset-react'], <-- correct
        // presets: ['solid'], <-- incorrect
    },
},
```